# 'Invalid or unexpected token' error in webview espresso test

Tags: android, webview, google-play, android-espresso

google play console pre-launch report, reports an exception occured in webview. but error log says its related to webview espresso testing:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in evaluationEvaluation: status: 13 value: {message=Invalid or unexpected token} hasMessage: true message: Invalid or unexpected token
```

I searched and did not see a fix for this. anyone else encounterd this issue?

Comment: have you found any solution on this?

Comment: nope, just ignored it.